# Angular JS form validation in "myApp" application.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-validation

I am new to AngularJS and try to implement form validation in "myApp" app.
I wrote the code below. The {{result}} should output "true"/"false". But it didn't work.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <form name = "myForm">
     <p>Input the field: </p>
        <input type = "text" name="myInput" ng-model = "myInput" required>
     </form>
        <p> The result:</p>
        <p>{{result}}</p>
        
    <script>
     var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.result = myForm.myInput.$valid;
  });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: You're using a very old version of AngularJs. I would at least upgrade to the latest stable version as any responses might be incompatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be correct code for your problem.
If you "watch" the changes in the "input field" then $valid result will generate.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController"> 
            <form name='myForm' novalidate>
            <p>Input the field: </p>
             <input type='text' ng-model='model.name' name='myInput' required/> 
            </form>
            <p> The result:</p>
            <p>{{myForm.myInput.$valid}}</p>
    <script> 
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('MyController',['$scope',function($scope) {
                $scope.$watch('myForm.myInput.$valid',function(newValue,oldvalue) {
                if(newValue) { 
                    //do anything with new value
                }
            });
        }]); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: I get it Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As a new User to angularJS your approcach is some how correct in form validation.In future you will learn new vesions in angular and several validation methodologies.
following code line is the way that how we can check valid input in angularJS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>  
<body ng-app="">

<p>Try writing in the input field:</p>

<form name="myForm">
<input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" required>
</form>

<p>The input's valid state is:</p>
<h1>{{myForm.myInput.$valid}}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Your approach is correct.Keep it up and it will be great if you can define correct question clearly. :) 
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. I also saw your provided code in W3 school which I am studying from there. My code was based on there to make some change. Basically, I want to express the validation result based on my controller. (e.g app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.result = myForm.myInput.$valid;) 
Can you point out where my code get error? Thank you

Comment: Added corrections to my previous answer after compile and testing your code. hope that will be helpful.I think without "watch" functionality controller will not get any response signal unless you use $dirty, ng-change etc.